# Specifying end_of_line for seperate os in .editorconfig

Tags: .net, build, format, editorconfig

I have a .editorconfig file, and i'm using it for format check during build.

I have specified end_of_line in the .editorconfig file.
The problem is when i set its value to "lf", build passes in ubuntu, but fails in windows.
while, when the value of end_of_line is "crlf", it fails in ubuntu, but passes in windows.

How can i make sure that the build passes in both the OS? Is there a way to add condition or maybe set it's value to "auto"?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't a way to do this with the `.editorconfig`.

However, maybe you get a idea when you read the discussion in [a feature request](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/226) about that topic.